# IEnumerable<Hashtable> to DictionaryEntry using Linq

Tags: c#, linq

I'm trying to use Linq to get all `DictionaryEntry` objects from an `IEnumerable<Hashtable>` but for the life of me can't figure out how to do it.

I mean the most obvious thing for me would be to use `.SelectMany(x => x).Cast<DictionaryEntry>()` to try to flatten it, but that doesn't work!

Anyone has any ideas how this can be done using Linq alone?

**EDIT**

I've got the following code that works, trying to convert this to Linq:

```
var t = new Dictionary<string, object>();

foreach (PSObject obje in objects)
{    
    foreach (DictionaryEntry entry in (Hashtable) obje.BaseObject)
    {
        t.Add((string) entry.Key, entry.Value);
    }
}

return t;
```

I've got this far with trying to convert this to Linq:

`objects.Cast<PSObject>().Select(x => (Hashtable) x.BaseObject)`, which leaves me with a `IEnumerable<Hashtable>` but like I said, can't find a way to get the `DictionaryEntry` objects from there.

Comment: It would be helpful if you gave full sample code, or the definition of `Hashtable` and `DictionaryEntry`.

Comment: @AndrewCooper what do you even mean _by the definition of `Hashtable` and `DictionaryEntry`_ ??

Comment: @Andrew They're framework classes. But if you insist: [Hashtable](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/Collections/hashtable.cs) and [DictionaryEntry](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/Collections/dictionaryentry.cs,bc17973c0d3568e6)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Would something like this work for you?

```
var t = objects
    .Select(e => e.BaseObject)
    .OfType<Hashtable>()
    .SelectMany(e => e.Cast<DictionaryEntry>())
    .ToDictionary(e => (string)e.Key, e => e.Value);
```

It:

1. Selects all of the BaseObject values.
2. Finds all of type Hashtable
3. Selects all of the DictionaryEntry values.
4. Combines them all into a dictionary.

Note that you will get an `ArgumentException` if there is a duplicate key in any of the Hashtables. That is an issue with your existing solution too, however. You could get around this by using `.GroupBy(...)` and selecting the first item, or making a decision in some other way.

You will also get an `InvalidCastException` when you try to convert the key to a string if the key is not a string. This is also an issue with your current solution. You could add a `.Where(e => e.Key is string)` below the `.SelectMany(...)` to filter out any entries with keys that are not strings.

Comment: Works like a charm. It's obvious now that I needed the cast inside the SelectMany, not outside like I was trying. Sometimes all you need is a good night sleep! In this particular case I'm guaranteed there will be no duplicate keys (this used to be a Dictionary that was serialized and is now in the process of being deserialized, though somehow it's deserialized as a Hashtable)